# AWS - Spring boot/Angular deployment to elastic beanstalk connecting to rds database instance

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I am having trouble with connecting spring-boot to rds database instance when it's deployed onto elastic beanstalk. I followed a guide https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-deployment, which helped me turn my app into a jar file and then deployed it onto elastic beanstalk. The thing is that the project works perfectly fine when I am running the jar file from the command line (locally), but as soon as I upload the jar file onto elastic beanstalk and go to the URL provided it seems to not be connecting to rds.
I do know, however, that it may be because of my base and search URL in my angular application because in my typescript files my URL's are

```
private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/products";
private search = "http://localhost:8080/api/product-category";
```

and in the web console, I am receiving the

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/product-category. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

But I'm unsure what to change the "localhost:8080" part of the URL to. Please feel free to let me know if I should provide anything else. I also wanted to add that I do see my angular application on the URL provided, but the website just seems to not be retrieving from the database.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone goes through this trouble also:
I configured my server.port = 5000 in my application.properties file
I went to my angular and changed the link http://localhost:8080 to {aws provided url}/api/products and for the other one also
I changed my angular url to localhost:5000 if I want to make any changes.

so I added an if statement that initializes the url to localhost:5000 if I am working locally, otherwise change to {aws provided url} if I deployed the web application onto elastic beanstalk.

Overall: it turns out that I was connecting to the database, but I did not configure my angular links correctly, therefore I was not retrieving from the correct link.